# JS - Referenced external js library causing error ("invalid regular expression flag")

Tags: jquery

I have an external library jQuery.aSimpleTour (a web app tour plugin) that I have included within an angular application.

My current page address is /#/app/account-settings-confirm

My referenced js is included as follows.

```
<script src="resources/js/simpletour/jquery.aSimpleTour.js"></script>
```

Upon opening the page I keep receiving the following Firefox FireBug console error.

```
Syntax error - invalid regular expression flag a

/app/account-settings-confirm
    / \
     |   
-----
```

jquery.aSimpleTour.js line 1 col 5 is the triggering point for the error.

This is what line 1 up to line 13 looks like:

```
1    /**
2     * jQuery aSimpleTour
3     *
4     * @version 1.0.6
5     * @description jQuery Tour web
6     * @author alvaro.veliz@gmail.com
7     */
8    
9    (function($) {
10    
11        var settings = {
12           data: [],
13            autoStart: false,
...
```

What does this mean and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Two issues.  One, my Firebug did not point to the current line so I used the browser inspector which pointed to the line and since my address has a hash which apparently the library uses get the current step # for displaying the popup for the tour, I will need to compensate for this to work around based on the current addressing scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

To overcome the issue I added charCount method to use within the load event handler of the library.

Within load handler I modified the parsing section to handle two hash characters properly within the context of my applications use of /#/ in the url.

**Modified code**

```
 function charCount(str, chr){
            return str.length - str.replace(new RegExp(chr, 'g'), "").length;
        }

    $(window).load(function(){
        var tourStep;
        loc = window.location.href;
        numHashes = charCount(loc, '#');
        if (loc.indexOf("/#/") === -1 && numHashes == 1)
          tourStep = loc.substr(1).split('=');
        else if (numHashes == 2)
        {
          str  = loc.substr(loc.indexOf('#')+1);
          tourStep = (str.substr(str.indexOf('#')+1)).split('=');
        }
        if (typeof(tourStep) != 'undefined' && typeof(eval(tourStep[0])) != 'undefined' && typeof(eval(tourStep[1])) != 'undefined') {
            $.aSimpleTour(eval(tourStep[0]), tourStep[1]);
        }
    });
```